# What is Avg Time and Time in the ants profiler?

Tags: .net, performance, performance-testing, ants

In the column of the ants profiler we can see
`Hit Count :` the number of time which the instruction is called.
`Avg Time :`?
`Time :`?

What is the difference between `Avg Time` and `Time`?

Comment: I'm going out of a limb here, but I'm going to guess `Avg Time` is average time and `Time` is maybe total time? Does `Time / Hit Count = Avg Time`?

Comment: No some time i have Hit cout = 2,319,044 ; avg time : 0,00 ; times: 6544
the instruction is: long b=2;

Comment: `6,544/2,319,044 = 0.0028`, rounded to 2 d.p. would be `0.00`, so that would be entirely consistent.

Comment: sorry they display the average time with 0,000 and their are value like 0.009 so